# How to leave a voice channel without member

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is the part of the code for my command! Although it's only this part that I can't figure out very well! I am trying to make the bot leave after a queue is finished!

```
if (!url){
          fs.unlinkSync(`checker/${message.guild.id}.json`);
          fs.unlinkSync(`files/${message.guild.id}.json`);
          fs.unlinkSync(`number/${message.guild.id}.json`);
          connection.leave();
          message.channel.send("The Queue Finished so I left!");
        }
```

The part where it says `!url` and the `fs.unlink` works it's just making the bot leave the voice channel is a problem that I can't figure out! I have tried the following:

```
message.member.voice.channel.leave();
message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave();
voiceChannel.leave();
(I have also tried to get the id of the vc and leave but gave me errors)
```

EDIT:
`const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;`
This is what voiceChannel is defined!

Comment: That's odd, I tried that out with my bot and it seemed to work. What was the error when you tried to do `voiceChannel.leave()`?

Comment: The thing is I am trying to make it so even if the user has already left it should leave, but it gives me errors since there is no member inside the vc for it to leave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

```
if (!url){
          fs.unlinkSync(`checker/${message.guild.id}.json`);
          fs.unlinkSync(`files/${message.guild.id}.json`);
          fs.unlinkSync(`number/${message.guild.id}.json`);
          connection.leave();
          client.channels.cache.get('<channel ID here>').leave();
          message.channel.send("The Queue Finished so I left!");
        }
```

I'm not entirely sure how you are storing the channel ID so you will need to fill that in yourself.